how do I use toggle comment in HTML in my vscode? (for windows)
even on pressing ctrl + / , the code isn't commented out
even on pressing the required keys , my VS code isn't working as I expect it to. I went to the emmet documentation for help and it worked on the site's "try it yourself" section but not on my VScode

Can you show a screenshot of your VSCode? Is the language for the file being set correctly?

You have already verified that you have configured the 'Keyboard shortcuts' in VScode?

@PsychoMx I am not sure if I enabled keyboard shortcuts for it. how do I do it?

@AngYC  everything else is working great , I was just going through a video tutorial to learn HTML and I tried copying  the comment shortcut for commenting a line , but it did not work on my VScode

File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and search for 'Toggle Line Comment'. You should see Ctrl + / on the right.
If not, you can click the pencil icon on the right to assign this keyboard shortcut to the comment action.
If it's still not working, there might be a conflict with another extension or setting. You can try disabling other extensions to see if that resolves the issue.

If I remember correctly, the default key is Ctrl + }

alt+ shift + a when the line is selected
